# Merge two list (java 7)

Tags: java, list, merge

I have two lists of `Personne`:  `listOne` and `listTwo`.

`Personne` is:

```
public class Personne{
    private String name;
    private Favorite favorite;
    private Collection<Number>  numbers;
}

public class Favorite{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

For each item, I want to merge the two lists if the favorite name and id of the first list equals the favorite name and id of the second list, and then merge the second list to first.

This is a part of my treatement and what i means by merge (its not create an other list ) :

if my condition is true i want to take item of my first list :

```
item.setNumbers(item2.getnumbers);
```

What is the best way to do this with Java 7?

Comment: Why not create a new list, loop over the other two and add them? (Next to that, your question context is incorrect, you say you have a list of Personne, but you are talking about the Favorite of the list.)

Comment: because my list contains favortie  and the favorite contains other feilds . i want just test favorite name and id if my condition is true i want to complete my item with item of second list

Comment: To compare the favorites, you should make an equals(Object other) method, (http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) However, the requested result is still not clear to me, can you give an example and the wanted result?

Comment: I need just to test favorite id and name(favorite contains others feild) and if my condition is true i want to take my item of my first list and complete it with item of second list information like item.setNumbers(item2.getnumbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try iterating over listOne, check for each desired item if it's in listTwo and in that case add the entries from listOne and listTwo to a new list.

Something like

https://gist.github.com/a2465b03fb7503f9c8190ab72c328c10

Comment: the favorite class contans other feild so the equals method should have just two field (name and id ) ? and if true i want to complete item with other field of item 2 like: 
  for (Personne per1:listOne){
         for (Personne per2:listTwo){
           if (per1.getFavorite().equals(per2.getFavorite())){
             per1.setNumbers(per2.getNumbers())
             listMerged.add(per1);
           }
         }
}

thank you for you answer

Comment: Using interpunction, `code`for code and a little bit of "formatting" in the sense of line breaks would help me a lot in understanding what you'd like to do.

Comment: I understand you want to merge only the `numbers`-property from the Favorites list into the corresponding Personne from the Personne list, correct?

Comment: yes its  exactely what i want (if the favorite name and id of the first list equals the favorite name and id of the second list)

Comment: but how can i implement equals methode in favorite because it contains others feild but i want just id and name??

thank you for suggestion

Comment: As for the implementation of your own equals-method, I suggest you read up on the topic here at SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood, we want to get a list containing all unique elements of both lists without duplicates.

First let's create an equals() method for the classes which is needed for ArrayList.contains() method to function properly:

```
class Favorite {
    ...
    private boolean equals(Favorite other) {
        int i = id.compareTo(other.id);
        if (i != 0) return false;

        return (name.compareTo(other.name) == 0);
    }

class Personnel {
    ...
    private boolean equals(Personnel other) {
        int i = name.compareTo(other.name);
        if (i != 0) return false;

        return favorite.equals(other.favorite); 
    }
```

Since there is no guarantee that input lists are sorted, we can write merging method like this:

```
    public List<Personnel> merge(List<Personnel> listOne, List<Personnel> listTwo) {
        List<Personnel> result = new ArrayList<>(listOne);

        for (Personnel p : listTwo) {
            if (!result.contains(p)) {
                result.add(p);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I need just to test favorite id and name and not name of personne  and if my condition is true i want  to take my item of my first list  and complete it with item of second list information like  item.setNumbers(item2.getnumbers). but you answer  has clarified my idea